# I bent a rim, what kind of new rim should I buy?

Tags: wheels

I bent a rim on a wheel that has a tire that’s 25-622 (700x25E). What kind of new rim should I buy?

What kind of rim is compatible with this tire? I do not know how to size rims.

Comment: https://www.sheldonbrown.com/rim-sizing.html

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the maximum or minimum tire width I can fit on my bicycle](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/52587/what-is-the-maximum-or-minimum-tire-width-i-can-fit-on-my-bicycle)

Comment: The simplest solution is to just take the wheel into a bike shop and say, "Hi. Can you sell me one of these that isn't bent, please?" Sure, it's great to have skill and knowledge but this shouldn't be a problem that you need to solve often, so why make it hard for yourself?

Comment: How sharp is the bend? Maybe you could unbend it.

Answer (score 3):

You say you want to replace the rim, but unless the hub is something special, or you're going to rebuild the wheel yourself, it's probably cheaper to replace the whole wheel.

If you're replacing the rim, apart from approximately matching the rim width ([see Sheldon Brown](https://www.sheldonbrown.com/rim-sizing.html)) you also need to match the number of spoke holes if you want to reuse your hub, and it's a good idea to replace the spokes that have been damaged. If you have rim brakes also need to make sure your new rim has a braking surface.

If you're replacing the wheel, you need to match the hub type and size. The type could be quick release (QR), thru axle (of which there are a couple of sizes) or nutted with dropouts (again multiple sizes). The relevant size is the over locknut distance - the width of the hub. You also need to know whether your old wheel used disc or rim brakes, and if did, what type and rotor size.

Comment: I suspect that somebody who knows how to rebuild the wheel isn't going to have to ask this question, so they're probably looking to buy a new wheel.

Comment: @DavidRicherby you're probably right, but I like to assume that an OP is using a term correctly until the evidence convinces me otherwise.  They could be expecting that their best option is to buy a rim and get their LBS to rebuild the wheel - I thought so too the first time I broke a rim.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to directly replace the rim you need to match the rim diameter, width and number of spokes.

The rim diameter is ISO/ERTRO 622 i.e. 622 mm, commonly know as 700c.

Rim width you can easily measure if you have the bent rim (or the other wheel, assuming it's matched). It's the inner width between the tire bead hooks. You don't need a replacement that exactly matches as tires have a range of rim widths they will work with.

As others have said it's is often cheaper and easier to replace a whole wheel than repair one. Unless the replacement rim is an exact match the inner diameter of the rim will be different, which requires different length spokes. Spokes often need to be replaced in a wheel build anyway. That means you are only re-using the hub and the cost of wheel building process can be significant.

There are few existing questions about replacing whole wheels and what you need to know. Try this [one](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/q/63803/24228).